# Why does this C program print weird characters in output?

Tags: c, operator-precedence, getchar, control-characters

I've the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int ch;
        while( ch = getchar() != '\n') {
                printf("Read %c\n",ch);
        }  
        return 0;
}
```

No matter what I enter I get:

```
Read
```

Why is this happening and what is that weird char that I see?

Stackoverflow is not printing the weird char. You can see it here: http://ideone.com/EfZHr

Comment: If you were using gcc, make sure you have the -Wall flag set.  Amongst the many common problems it reports is this one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to place parenthesis as:

```
while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n')
```

[**Precedence**](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) of `!=` is greater than that of `=`

```
while( ch = getchar() != '\n')
```

is same as:

```
while( ch = (getchar() != '\n') )
```

which reads a char compares it with newline and then assigns the result of comparison to ch. Now the result of comparison is `0` (when newline is entered) or `1` (when anything else is entered)

The weird char you're seeing is the [**control char**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) with value `1`, there is no printable symbol for ASCII 1, so I guess its the shell that prints the weird char with value `0001` in it.

You can confirm it by piping your program output to octal dump (od) :

```
$ echo 'a' | ./a.out | od -bc         # user entered 'a'
0000000 122 145 141 144 040 001 012
          R   e   a   d     001  \n
here you go  ----------------^


$ echo '\n' | ./a.out | od -bc        # user entered '\n'
0000000
```

GCC when used with `-Wall` warns you as:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

Comment: Same precedence lookup reference :D

Answer (score 2):

C (and C++) interpret the while loop as:

```
while( ch = (getchar() != '\n')) {
```

So `ch` gets the value `1` (for true), which is an unprintable character. You should use explicit parenthesis to fix the precedence:

```
 while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
```

Comment: Ah, indeed. But this applies for both :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ch = getchar() != '\n'
```

Writing this will cause unexpected behavior depending on the languages [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). In C `=` is evaluated after `!=` so `ch` will be true or false. Try:

```
(ch = getchar()) != '\n'
```

Comment: Don't you have any cleaner words meaning fail miserably?

Comment: I do in fact - don't know why I chose that wording yesterday, but changed it.