# C++: Pointer assignment warning on strchr()

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-warnings

I get the error `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast` on the following code, what does it mean?

```
char * splitter;
if(splitter = strchr(key, ':') != NULL && *(splitter + 1) == ' ')
```

Comment: Related (not duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626905/why-does-this-c-program-print-weird-characters-in-output/3626912#3626912

Comment: For the sake of readability you should move the assignment out of the if statement. Also `*(splitter+1)` is equivalent to `splitter[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the priority of operations. You need to put an extra set of parens to make sure it happens in the right order:

```
char * splitter;
if((splitter = strchr(key, ':')) != NULL && *(splitter + 1) == ' ')
```

otherwise the it will evaluate as this:

```
splitter = (strchr(key, ':') != NULL)
```

Since `strchr(key, ':') != NULL` will evaluate to either a `1` or a `0`, in your example, you are assigning an integer to a pointer type, hence the warning.

however, i would just write it as in your second example, since it is simpler and less error prone. Making it one line shorter doesn't add anything except complexity.

Comment: I'd write `splitter[1]` instead of `*(splitter + 1)`, too.

Answer (score 2):

The not-equal operator != has higher precedence than the assignment operator =, so your original line reads like `splitter = (strchr(key, ':') != NULL)` rather than your intended `(splitter = strchr(key, ':)) != NULL`, so the compiler tries to assign to splitter the result of the comparison between strchr() and NULL.

Answer (score 1):

The `!=` operator has a higher precedence than the `=` operator. That means your expression `splitter = strchr(key, ':') != NULL` is actually interpreted as `splitter = (strchr(key, ':') != NULL)`.

Put the assignment into parentheses to increase the precedence of that part:

```
(splitter = strchr(key, ':')) != NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The `!=` has higher precendence than the `=`.  You should fully parenthesize:

```
if (((splitter = strchr(key, ':')) != NULL) && (*(splitter + 1) == ' '))
```